# (Flutter) Curved edge to a CustomPaint Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, custom-painting

This is what I want to build:

(Just see the shape of the `appBar` and not the contents)

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

I want the edge to be curved, and not so sharp.

Here is my code for the `CustomPaint`:

```
class LogoPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - size.height / 5);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 1.2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - size.height / 5);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**How do I achieve this curved edge?**

I have tried `point.arcToPoint()` and `point.quadraticBezierTo()`, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but you can fiddle with the numbers a bit more:

```dart
class LogoPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - size.height / 5);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 1.2, size.height);
    //Added this line
    path.relativeQuadraticBezierTo(15, 3, 30, -5);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - size.height / 5);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This code gives this result: 
[image: Curved bezier app bar background]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
class LogoPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - size.height / 5);
    //Use the method conicTo
    path.conicTo(size.width / 1.2, size.height, size.width,
        size.height - size.height / 5, 15);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVPTn.png)